# What is the difference between Identity object in Request/Response and Principal?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, identityserver4, identity, claims-based-identity

I'm using .NET 6 and Identity Server 4.

What is the difference between these three Identities (this is a class derived from OpenIdConnectEvents)?

Why are there claims in the `principalIdentity` but not in the `requestIdentity`/`responseIdentity`?

```
    private Task OnTicketReceivedImpl(TicketReceivedContext context)
    {
        var requestIdentity = context.Request.HttpContext.User.Identity;
        var responseIdentity = context.Response.HttpContext.User.Identity;
        var principalIdentity = context.Principal?.Identity;
        ...
    }
```

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=net-7.0)  It suggests the claims are there you just need to cast it.

Comment: @AliK cast what to what? The `User` and `Principal` properties are already of type `ClaimsPrincipal`.

Comment: Did you see the link it is iterating over the user from the HttpContext with claims.

Comment: @AliK I can see that. However I don't understand what I need to cast. In the example, the only cast I can see is `HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal`, however this would be redundant for me because the `User` is already a `ClaimsPrincipal`.